# iOS Provisioning Portal - 2 developers - provisioning profiles invalid for one developer

Tags: ios, provisioning

I can't figure out what the correct way of working with the Provisioning Portal is. Here is our situation:

- 2 developer accounts, 2 different computers, same team
- one certificate in Provisioning Portal > Certificates > Distribution. The certificate includes two distribution profiles

My problem is that the two distribution provisioning profiles are always invalid for one of the developers. We got into that situation by "starting fresh": revoking both development and distribution certificates, then creating new ones from either of the developers' machines. As soon as new certificates are created, the provisioning profiles become invalid. I guess I understand why that happens. What I can't understand is how to do everything so that both developers can work with valid certificates.

Answer (score 3):

have one of the developers export his certificate from the keychain, along with it's private key and send it to the other one. Should work fine that way for both.

Comment: We're using two different developer accounts (I updated the question to reflect this). Does your answer still apply?

Comment: Moving a private key around seems to defeat the purpose of private keys. Do you maybe have another suggestion?

Comment: well you can have both your developers issue certificate signing requests with their own name / private key and the only thing they would have to change on build phase of their project would the codesign profile, so that each use their own. Or you can skip even that, and xcode would automatically match the profile && identity for each if they use the automatic profile selector option.

Comment: That's what we tried, but after one developer issues a CSR, the two distribution provisioning profiles become invalid on the other developer's computer "Valid signing identity not found".